$E[f(X_{u+\delta})| \mathcal{F}_{u}] = f(X_{u}) + \delta \sum_{y} q_{u,y}f(y) + O(\delta^{2})$
I've been reading the following notes and wanted to sharpen my understanding of the following statement in the proof of lemma 1.1.
$E[f(X_{u+\delta})| \mathcal{F}_{u}] = f(X_{u}) + \delta \sum_{y} q_{u,y}f(y) + O(\delta^{2})$
Here $X_{t}$ is a continuous reversible Markov chain on a finite state space and $q_{u,y}$ is element of the Laplacian $\mathcal{L}f(x) = \sum_{y} q_{x,y}f(y)$ with $q_{x,x} = -\sum_{y \neq x} q_{x,y}$.
An example could be the continuous time process associated to a discrete random walk on a graph where one makes "jumps" in according to an exponential distribution and transitions to a state space according to the transition function of the random walk.
I believe this statement, but I was looking for some rigorous justification for it, especially the $O(\delta^{2})$ term.
